# Variable 'wordlist' must be initialized error in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I 'm trying to fetch data from internet using jsoap in kotlin. I fetched data from internet and I want to assigned it to a property that I declared to use easily again but I got this error. I know it is very simple error but I want to learn bacground of issiue. First of all I declared a property and assigned it to datas from internet in the scope but when I want to use it outside of scope it accours this error. What I don't understand is that I have already assigned the data from the internet to this variable, why does it want to initialize the variable again? and when I define it like this,

```
var wordList : MutableList<ExtractedData>?=null
```

the error goes away, but then the data outside the scope is null or empty in the console. But again, the data in the scop I made fetchdata continues to come properly, there is no problem there again.

**My Code**

```
@Composable
fun MostUsedWordScreen(viewModel: MostUsedWordScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

    var wordList : MutableList<ExtractedData>

    viewModel.fetchData().observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current, Observer {
        wordList = it
        println("inside wordlist"+wordList)
    })

    println("outside wordlist"+wordList)

    MostUsedWordItem(wordArray = wordList)


}
```

**My error**

```
Variable 'wordList' must be initialized
```

Comment: Is all the code in the "My Code" block inside a single function? Or is wordList defined outside the function as a class property? You're working with what looks like Android LiveData. All your code that works with the list should be *inside* the observer because you need to react to it changing. Code outside the observer is called before the live data has arrived. You probably shouldn't have a local copy of the list at all, but only be working with what comes in inside the observer scope.

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying thanks so how can I copy it variable in observe scope or how can I use outside of scope wordlist after initialize in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable unless it has definitely been already initialized. Let's take a look at your function body:

```
var wordList : MutableList<ExtractedData>

viewModel.fetchData().observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current, Observer {
    wordList = it
    println(wordList) //-->here it shows data from internet there is no problem
```

At this point, the compiler knows that `wordList` has definitely been initialized, since you assign to it in this block, just a couple of statements above.

```
})
```

Now you're outside the block, and at this point the compiler doesn't know whether the above block that assigns to `wordList` will have been executed or not. If it hasn't been executed, `wordList` will not be initialized.

```
println(wordList)//-->but here it wants to be initialized again
```

Hence you get this error. It doesn't "want to be initialized *again*" - it may not have been initialized even once.

```
MostUsedWordItem(wordArray = wordList)
```

And again here, `wordList` is being used without having definitely been initialized.

I've just given you the reason for the error message. The solution to your problem is given by Tenfour's comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

LiveData must be reacted to. It doesn't make sense to copy a value received in the observer into a local variable that is used outside the observer's scope, because the observer will be called after all the other code is already done using the local variable with its initial value.

But since you're using Compose, you can use State to treat LiveData just like a variable. Then it will trigger recomposition when new values arrive. This is effectively similar to how it would look to put all your code inside the Observer block, except that you can call other Composables and it is much cleaner, especially if there are multiple LiveData to work with. Use `observeAsState()` as a variable delegate to do this:

```
@Composable
fun MostUsedWordScreen(viewModel: MostUsedWordScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

    val wordList: List<ExtractedData> by viewModel.fetchData().observeAsState()

    MostUsedWordItem(wordArray = wordList)

}
```

Comment: when i do what you said i get this error: Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.

Comment: I was assuming your LiveData was a `LiveData<List<ExtractedData>>`, if it's not, change the wordList's type to whatever your LiveData's generic type is. Or just delete the explicit type `: List<ExtractedData>` and allow it to be inferred.